# Как ускорить работу программы на Selenium?

Tags: java, многопоточность, selenium, производительность

У меня написана программа на Selenium. При ее запуске обрабатывается параллельно 6 сайтов с помощью многопоточности Java. Проблема в том, что при одновременном запуске и работе шести потоков программа работает очень долго, хотя результаты программы нужно получать быстро. Как можно это исправить и можно ли? Можно ли повысить производительность компьютера каким-то образом или все зависит от программы?

Comment: Фоновые потоки могут длиться долго, но промежуточные результаты можно получить сразу.

Comment: В selenium самая долгая операция - ожидание загрузки страницы, которая реализуется несколькими способами, возможно стоит оптимизировать этот момент.